# Stock size, trim size, bleed area, safety margin -- Memoir

Tags: margins, memoir, publishing, bleed

**Problem:** I'm self-publishing through BookVault (switched from Amazon KDP) and have the following BookVault template for the text:

[image]

Using the Memoir package I use `\setstocksize{285mm}{222mm}` to set the stock size, as indicated in the template. My understanding is that the trim size is 279mm x 216mm, which could be set using `\settrimmedsize{279mm}{216mm}{*}` or alternatively, by `\setpagecc{279mm}{216mm}{*}`, I think.  But I'm unclear how to set the bleed and safety margin in the template. It reads to me like the bleed is actually what will be trimmed away, but that also the safety margin area could be trimmed away too like a margin of error for trimming.

If it has any bearing, I am typesetting the book with TeX but submitting the PDF output to the printer/disributer.

My preamble with MWE:

```
% BEGIN PREAMBLE

\documentclass[fleqn,12pt]{memoir}
\setstocksize{285mm}{222mm}
\setpagecc{279mm}{216mm}{*} %cc means positioning page center-center. See Memoir manual p.73
\checkandfixthelayout[fixed]
\pagestyle{headings}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt} %this line is needed to use 12pt font size
\usepackage{calc}

\makeevenhead{headings}{My Running Header}{}{}
\makeoddhead{headings}{}{}{My Running Header}
\makeevenfoot{headings}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{headings}{}{}{\thepage}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in} %shrinks margins
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}

\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.75in}

% END PREAMBLE

\begin{document}

\clearpage

\vspace*{30pt}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.38]{book_text.png}
\captionof*{figure}{\uppercase{BookVault Text Template}\\ 11" x 8.5", Paper Mache}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

**Update:** Reading through the Memoir documentation plus rallg's answer I came up with the following preamble which hopefully someone with Memoir knowledge can verify.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt]{memoir}

%paper size and margins
\setstocksize{285mm}{222mm} %sets printer stock size
\settrimmedsize{279mm}{216mm}{*} %sets final trimmed size
\settrims{3mm}{3mm} %specifies top amount and fore-edge amount to be trimmed; o/w it's zero and the trimmed size isn't 3mm all the way around
\setlrmarginsandblock{24.7mm}{12.7mm}{*} %sets spine margin and fore-edge margin, and includes the printer's specified safety margin
\setulmarginsandblock{17.7mm}{24.05mm}{*} %sets upper margin plus safety margin and lower margin plus safety margin
\checkandfixthelayout[fixed] %required to use Memoir macros

\pagestyle{plain} %no headers needed; only a footer with page number
\makeevenfoot{plain}{\thepage}{}{} %page number placement in footer
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{\thepage} %page number placement in footer

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
```

Comment: reading between the lines, it looks like your printer wants at least 12mm of binding offset. So another option is to use `\setbinding`; this is convenient when you just want to set the width of the typeblock and let memoir figure out the margins. (This is potentially useful if later down the road you wish to switch printers who give you a slightly different trim size.)

Comment: @WillieWong I went with a set-the-margins first approach, hopefully correctly, and let that determine the textwidth and textheight sizes.  It's a book a images, and the real challenge is getting them scaled horizontally so that they show enough detail.  As a result I've set the spine and outer margin almost as small as I could.  It's really only about four of the images that come close to the outer edge out of about 85.

Answer (score 2):

I have used print-on-demand, more than once. Although I use my own custom document class, this advice is generally applicable:

The "safety" zone is a term used by printers, not TeX. It is not written into the PDF, not even in metadata. The printer is telling you that "live content,"
meaning something you expect must be visible in entirety, must not intrude into the safety zones. Compare that to "bleed," which is related, but applies to graphics that extend to the page edges.

When you set trim size less than paper size (different TeX packages use different terms), that information effectively defines bleed. But it does not have anything to do with the safety zone. In PDF/X format, the bleed may be written into metadata.

To set the safety zone, set the margins, so that your "live content" is blocked from the safety zone, by the width of the margins.

When creating a cover image, setting margins alone is not enough. You must also account for the safety zone at rear, spine, and front. Also, the printer will tell you that the spine "live content" must be less in (sideways) width than the spine width.

If you are not using a TeX package that provides for cover creation, it is possible to achieve the results by using package `textpos` to absolutely position things. Then you can load the template into document background,
position text boxes as you see fit (and rotate for the spine). After that works, you would remove the template and substitute the actual graphics.

If I am unclear, let me know in a comment.

In any case: Whether you send them a PDF with only raster graphics, or one with graphics and text, the printer reduces it to raster. The raster is usually at 300 pixels per inch (even if the printer could do better) for color work. In that case, there is no advantage to creating a PDF with text over graphics. You could create the whole thing, text and all, in a graphics program, then export as raster at 300 pixels/inch. No TeX required for that. You could also create blocks of text/drawings in TeX, then rasterize the PDF, trim it, probably render white as transparent, and place the text blocks as layers in a graphics program. That is how I do it, but I have the relevant experience.

Comment: So then my stock and trim sizes are set correctly using the Memoir package.  For the Safety Margin would you suggest I just include that in my margin?  Do you know how to do this specifically using Memoir?  (I will focus on the dust jacket later using a different template and TeX package.)

Comment: If it has any bearing, I am typesetting the book with TeX but submitting the PDF output to the publisher.

Comment: @E2R0NS In nearly all cases, the printer does not care how you created the PDF. Either it is a valid, printable PDF according to specs, or it is not. A few printers will reject vector artwork (other than text) because sometimes syntax-valid vectors create printing-bad results; in that case, reduce to raster. Note: If print-on-demand, it is likely that the "publisher" is *you* not the place that prints and distributes the book. If in doubt, ask them.

Comment: @E2R0NS The safety margin can be regarded as the margin relative to trim size. You can easily set that at the top, bottom, and sides, but something else is required for the margin near spine. I believe memoir has a way to handle that (but I am not familiar with it). No matter what you set, if it fits the template, all good, because "margins" are not saved into the PDF. Only the position of objects is saved, not how they got there.

Comment: As a hypothetical, if I wanted 1" margins in the final printed book, then I should set my margins in TeX to actually be 1" plus the safety margin specified in the template, so that I get a 1" margin relative to the safety margin, right?

Comment: The general rule: If it looks correct, it is correct. If it looks wrong, it is wrong. Test margins however you wish. Then look at the resulting PDF. If it fits the template as required, correct. If it does not, wrong. I use a custom document class, so I am not sure what memoir is actually doing. The PDF does not have margins or safety zone (readable by machine). Every element of the PDF is in a box that defines its size. If the boxes all fit within the allowed area, you win. If not, you lose. How you created the boxes does not matter.